# Convert string to pandas df using read_csv

Tags: python, io, pandas

I'm trying to convert the following string to a Pandas dataframe:

```
'2477\t1974\t89.104.195.179\tDK\t17\t212711\x00\n1974\t2370\t212.10.164.160\tDK\t19\t213017\x00\n1974\t2370\t87.50.40.214\tDK\t17\t56743\x00\n'
```

The problem I'm encountering is that pandas converts each value to it's own column instead of 6 columns and 3 rows as desired.

```
pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='\t', lineterminator='\n', names=['a','b','c','d','e','f'])
```

I've tried playing around with some of the other read_csv parameters with no success. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By specifying raw `sep` and `lineterminator`, it works:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd
data = '2477\t1974\t89.104.195.179\tDK\t17\t212711\x00\n1974\t2370\t212.10.164.160\tDK\t19\t213017\x00\n1974\t2370\t87.50.40.214\tDK\t17\t56743\x00\n'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep=r'\t', lineterminator=r'\n', names=['a','b','c','d','e','f'])
```